# Error when processing InDesign document in Applescript

Tags: runtime-error, applescript, adobe-indesign

Recently upgraded to Adobe CC 2020 and my script will now not work. Also Script Editor changed class names.

I am getting an error such that:

error "Can’t get every page of alias \"Untitled - Data:Users:gregory:Desktop:FORUM_MayJun_0414_B Folder:FORUM_MayJun_0414_fortesting.indd\"." number -1728 from every «class page» of alias "Untitled - Data:Users:gregory:Desktop:FORUM_MayJun_0414_B Folder:FORUM_MayJun_0414_fortesting.indd"

Here is my script:

```
global WordDocName
global wrongText
global myStories
--set uniqueInCopyStories to {}
--set wrongText to "BASE"


set theDoc to choose file without multiple selections allowed
--set theDoc to POSIX path of theDoc

set theDocInfo to info for theDoc
set theDocName to name of theDocInfo
set theDocName to characters 1 thru -6 of theDocName as text
set WordDocName to theDocName
set theDocName to theDocName & return

set myStories to {}

my processFiles(theDoc)

set mylist to items 1 thru -1 of myStories

set firstList to mylist

set secondList to RemoveDuplicates(firstList)

--secondList --> {1, 2, 3, 4}



set mynewlist to {}
repeat with i from 1 to (count of secondList)
    set myitem to item i of secondList as text
    set end of mynewlist to myitem
end repeat

set mystring to mynewlist as string
--return mystring

my processWordDoc(theDocName, mystring, WordDocName)

on processFiles(theDoc)

    tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
        activate
        open theDoc

        tell theDoc
            set myPages to every «class page»
            repeat with i from 1 to count of myPages
                tell item i of myPages
                    set myTextFrames to (every «class txtf» of item i of myPages)
                    repeat with aTextFrame in myTextFrames
                        if «class plnk» of «class strp» of aTextFrame is not «constant senmnada» then
                            if «class strp»'s «class plnk»'s «class lnkt» of aTextFrame is "InCopyInterchange" then
                                set mystorytitle to «class sTtl» of aTextFrame's «class strp»
                                set myLabel to «class ptag» of aTextFrame
                                set myText to characters 1 thru -1 of mystorytitle as text
                                --if myText does not contain wrongText then

                                set myStory to aTextFrame's «class strp»'s contents
                                copy "Page " & (name of item i of myPages) & " " & mystorytitle & return & myLabel & return & myStory & return & return to end of myStories
                            end if
                        end if
                        --end if
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end repeat

        end tell
    end tell
end processFiles

on processWordDoc(theDocName, mystring, WordDocName)
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        set newDoc to make new document
        copy theDocName & mystring to content of text object of newDoc
        save as active document file name WordDocName
        my textblue()

    end tell
end processWordDoc

on textblue()
    with timeout of 60000 seconds
        tell application "Microsoft Word"
            set myPars to every paragraph of active document
            set myTitle to text object of paragraph 1 of active document
            set color index of font object of myTitle to blue
            repeat with aPar in myPars
                if content of text object of aPar starts with "Page" then

                    set myRange to text object of aPar

                    set color index of font object of myRange to blue
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end timeout
end textblue

on RemoveDuplicates(inputList)

    set outputList to {}

    repeat with i from 1 to length of inputList

        --    We make testItem a single-item list to ensure
        --    that sublists of the inputList are properly
        --    looked for in the outputlist.
        --
        set thisItem to item i of inputList
        set testItem to {thisItem}

        if (outputList does not contain testItem) then

            set end of outputList to thisItem

        end if

    end repeat

    return outputList

end RemoveDuplicates
```

What I don't understand is why my script thinks I am asking to get every page of every page, when it was automatic that every page would be every page of theDoc

Answer (score 1):

`theDoc` is an AppleScript alias specifier, but you are using it (also) as an InDesign document reference.

The easiest solution is to replace

```
tell theDoc
```

with

```
tell active document
```